# How reset CNAME WWW on Godaddy to default @ value

Tags: web, dns, record, reset

CName WWW record was changed and you want reset it to previous value @.How to do 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTXqn.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
1. Go to DNS Management
2. If you deleted WWW record, create new, if you have WWW record press edit.
3. In field "points to" isnert your domain name, without "www."prefix but with correct zone. For example "mydomain.com"
4. Press Save button. 
5. You restored CNAME WWW record with default value @

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIzA3.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted WWW record, create new CNAME with following details:

```
    HOST-> www
    Points to -> @
    TTL -> 1 hour
```

It may take sometime to reflect the changes, but will work definitely.